# Extract exname information

Tags: r-exams

I want create the `section` dynamically, not from `.Rnw` files. It can be done with `stitle` parameter of `exams2moodle()`.

The `stitle` should based on directory structure and I want add the value of `exname` from `.Rnw` file.

I think should use `read_metainfo` which returns the value of `exname` too. It works well if don't use `\Sexpr` but if `\Sexpr` appears in `\exsolution{...}` drop an error:

```
Error in string2num(exsolution) :
  all numeric items must be finite and non-missing
Calls: read_exercise -> read_metainfo -> string2num
In addition: Warning message:
In string2num(exsolution) : NAs introduced by coercion
Execution halted
```

The `foo.Rnw` file:

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
solution <- 10
@
\exname{foo}
\exsection{bar}
\extype{num}
\exsolution{\Sexpr{solution}}
\begin{question}
  Foo text...
\end{question}
```

The `read_metainfo("foo.Rnw")` fails. Do I something wrong? Should I try another way?

EDIT: after update of `exams` only appears the warning message and doesn't halt.

Comment: Ooops, should update the `exams` package. Now drops only a warning message. Question: do I right what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As conceptually *everything* in the exercise files could be generated dynamically, it is only possible to read the exercise after weaving it. This is because not only the content of the metainformation tags but even the entire tags could be generated by the code in the exercise.

The workhorse function that performs the *weave*, *read*, *transform*, and *write* steps underlying all `exams2xyz()` interfaces is `xexams()`. It defaults to just weaving (via `xweave()`) and reading (via `read_metainfo()`) an exercise without any transformation or writing. Thus you can do:

```
xexams("foo.Rnw")[[1]][[1]]$metainfo
```

The indexing is needed to select the first random replication of the first exercise, and then extracting the metainformation.